# How to add big bracket in Richtextbox in WFP vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I want to know how to add big bracket that is covering 4 or 5 lines in Rich Text Box in windows form program in visual studio. I am attaching an image for better understanding what I am trying to implement

[image]

I want to create similar to this but I am unable to do so. Is this implementable in Richtextbox or any other ways through which I can achieve similar results

Comment: Firstly, your question says Windows Forms, your title says WPF and there are no tags for either. Which is it? Secondly, a `RichTextBox` is not magic. It displays RTF formatted text. is there anything in the RTF specification for that? Have you looked, because you're supposed to look for yourself before posting a question here. If you haven't looked then you haven't encountered an actual issue so it's too soon to post here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I dont know if we could do so, and I haven't find any similar post over the internet that's why at the end I choose to post over here.